# GroupBy with SingleOrDefault in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by

I have 5 tables:

> NazelShifts
>
> Nazel
>
> Tank
>
> PersonnelNazelShifts
>
> Shift

sql query is:

```
SELECT     SUM(NazelShift.Eold) AS tEold, SUM(NazelShift.Er) AS tEr,     SUM(NazelShift.Ecf) AS tEcf, SUM(NazelShift.Esf) AS tEsf, SUM(NazelShift.ESale) AS tESale, Tank.FuelId, 
                      NazelShift.ShiftId, PersonnelNazelShift.PersonnelId
FROM        NazelShift INNER JOIN
                      Nazel ON NazelShift.NazelId = Nazel.NazelId AND NazelShift.NazelId = Nazel.NazelId INNER JOIN
                      Tank ON Nazel.TankId = Tank.TankId INNER JOIN
                      PersonnelNazelShift ON Nazel.NazelId = PersonnelNazelShift.NazelId INNER JOIN
                      Shift ON NazelShift.ShiftId = Shift.ShiftId AND PersonnelNazelShift.ShiftId = Shift.ShiftId
WHERE     (NazelShift.ShiftId = 1)
GROUP BY Tank.FuelId, NazelShift.ShiftId, PersonnelNazelShift.PersonnelId
```

NazelShift have pelation many to one with Nazel and Shift
also PersonnelNazelShift have relation many to one with Nazel and Shift.

diagram is http://jmp.sh/dlO3MTf

I need to run this query:

```
NazelShifts.Where(i => i.ShiftId == 1)
    .GroupBy(i => new 
    { 
        i.ShiftId,         
        i.Nazel.Tank.FuelId,
        i.Nazel.PersonnelNazelShifts.SingleOrDefault().PersonnelId 
    })
    .Select(i => new
    {
        i.Key.ShiftId,
        i.Key.PersonnelId,
        i.Key.FuelId,
        tEold = i.Sum(rr => rr.Eold),
        tEr = i.Sum(rr => rr.Er),
        tEcf = i.Sum(rr => rr.Ecf),
        tEsf = i.Sum(rr => rr.Esf),
        tESale = i.Sum(rr => rr.ESale)
    })
```

This works fine in LinqPad4 but in vs2012 throws an exception:

> "The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a
> final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in
> this instance instead."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault as the error is telling you

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault and null check before checking for property PersonnelId , otherwise argument null exception will appear.

Comment: @StephenKennedy It's worth remembering that not everyone here has English as their first language...

Comment: @DavidG Fair point but have a look at the revision history. #4 in particular.

Comment: @DavidG, it may be true, but here he'll get an answer in English anyway, won't he?

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution.

```
NazelShifts.Where(i => i.ShiftId == 1)
       .Join(Nazels,
                     ns => ns.NazelId,
                     n => n.NazelId,
                     (ns, n) => new { NS = ns, N = n })
        .Join(Shifts,
                       nsn => nsn.NS.ShiftId,
                       s => s.ShiftId,
                     (nsn, s) => new { NSN = nsn, S = s })           
        .Join(PersonnelNazelShifts,
                       nsns =>new{ nsns.NSN.N.NazelId,nsns.S.ShiftId},
                       pns =>new { pns.NazelId,pns.ShiftId},
                     (nsns, pns) => new { NSNS = nsns, PNS = pns }) 
    .Join(Tanks,
                       nsnspns => nsnspns.NSNS.NSN.N.TankId,
                       t => t.TankId,
                     (nsnspns, t) => new { NSNSpns = nsnspns, T = t })  
    .GroupBy(i => new {  i.T.FuelId,i.NSNSpns.NSNS.NSN.NS.ShiftId,i.NSNSpns.PNS.PersonnelId })  
    .Select(i => new
                              {
                                  i.Key.ShiftId,
                                  i.Key.PersonnelId,
                                  i.Key.FuelId,
                                  tEold = i.Sum(rr => rr.NSNSpns.NSNS.NSN.NS.Eold),
                                  tEr = i.Sum(rr => rr.NSNSpns.NSNS.NSN.NS.Er),
                                  tEcf = i.Sum(rr => rr.NSNSpns.NSNS.NSN.NS.Ecf),
                                  tEsf = i.Sum(rr => rr.NSNSpns.NSNS.NSN.NS.Esf),
                                  tESale = i.Sum(rr => rr.NSNSpns.NSNS.NSN.NS.ESale)// not used
                              })
```